# Java JNA mapping D2D1CreateFactory from D2D1

Tags: java, c++, jna

I was trying to map the function D2D1CreateFactory from the DLL D2D1.dll. From there I want to build up on creating a Direct2D Java mapping, but that's off-topic. I so far had this:

```
public WinNT.HRESULT D2D1CreateFactory(int factoryType, REFIID riid, ID2D1Factory.ByReference ppIFactory);
```

The ID2D1Factory looks like this:

```
public class ID2D1Factory extends IUnknown {

    public ID2D1Factory() { }

    public ID2D1Factory(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }

}
```

When I try to run my code using the code below, "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access" is thrown (when turning on JNA.setProtected()).

The code to run:

```
ID2D1Factory.ByReference ref= new ID2D1Factory.ByReference();
D2D1.INSTANCE.D2D1CreateFactory(0, new REFIID(new IID("06152247-6f50-465a-9245-118bfd3b6007").toByteArray()), ref);
```

I have no clue why. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks to technomage I was able to get the correct method declaration. The method should be declared like this:

```
public WinNT.HRESULT D2D1CreateFactory(int factoryType, REFIID riid, D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS opts, PointerByReference pref);
```

The D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS structure was mapped as following:

```
public static class D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS extends Structure {
    public int debugLevel;
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "debugLevel" });
    }
    public D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS() {}
    public D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS(int size) {
        super(new Memory(size));
    }
    public D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS(Pointer memory) {
        super(memory);
        read();
    }
}
```

Finally, the snippet to call the method:

```
D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS opts = new D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS();
PointerByReference pp = new PointerByReference();
D2D1.INSTANCE.D2D1CreateFactory(0, new REFIID(new IID("06152247-6f50-465a-9245-118bfd3b6007").toByteArray()), opts, pp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `D2D1CreateFactory` requires pointer types as third and fourth arguments (you are declaring only three arguments).

Assuming you insert the options pointer (a simple `struct *`), your final argument needs to be `PointerByReference`, since the function will be "returning" a pointer value in the address that you give it.

You can then use `PointerByReference.getValue()` to initialize a new `ID2D1Factory` instance (the `Structure.ByReference` in this case is superfluous, since by default all structures as function parameters are treated as `struct *` by JNA unless explicitly defined otherwise).

```
public WinNT.HRESULT D2D1CreateFactory(int factoryType, REFIID riid, D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options, ID2D1Factory ppIFactory);

public class D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS extends Structure { ... }

D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options = ...;
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();

D2D1.INSTANCE.D2D1CreateFactory(0, new REFIID(...), options, pref);
ID2D1Factory factory = new ID2D1Factory(pref.getValue());
```

And don't forget to call `Structure.read()` in your `ID2D1Factory(Pointer)` ctor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this out and get back with the results to inform other users.