# Java JNA class method from pointer

Tags: java, directx, jna

I was trying to get a function mapped from the Direct2D class ID2DFactory, which I managed to port using [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621505/java-jna-mapping-d2d1createfactory-from-d2d1/15621951).

Now the next step that I thought of was to use `Function.getFunction(` to get a function, and then use `function.invokeXXX()` to have a working method.

Now this seems harder than I thought. The code below is what I have tried to achieve my goal.

```
    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS opts = new D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS();
    PointerByReference pp = new PointerByReference();
    HRESULT hres = D2D1.INSTANCE.D2D1CreateFactory(0, new REFIID(new IID("06152247-6F50-465A-9245-118BFD3B6007").toByteArray()), opts, pp);
    //hres returns 0 which means it was successful.

    // I thought that, since pp is a reference to a reference to the Factory, 
    // that getValue().getPointer(0) would give me the Factory, and thus the
    // first Pointer 'ReloadSystemMetrics()'.
    Function fnc = Function.getFunction(pp.getValue().getPointer(0).getPointer(0), Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
    fnc.invokeInt(null); // I have aswell tried new Object[] {}. This does not throw an error.

    //This is (or should be) GetDesktopDpi(Float*, Float*).
    Function fncGetdpi = Function.getFunction(pp.getValue().getPointer(0).getPointer(1), Function.ALT_CONVENTION); 
    FloatByReference x, y;
    x = y = new FloatByReference();
    fncGetdpi.invokeVoid(new Object[] {x, y}); //But this gives 'Invalid memory access'
```

I have had no luck yet in achieving what I wanted. Hopefully someone can give my insight in what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: Hi Bart. Did you get this right at all eventually? I see its been 3 months?

Comment: Sadly I have not been able to. I keep checking this often, but without any luck.